# "import" dependencies solution for assetic

Tags: javascript, symfony, import, dependencies, assetic

I am looking for some solution for using @import '*.js' like in less css for Symfony 2 project.
Is there any plugin for that? It would be nice to in-file controlling instead of hard writing 'javascripts' in correct order in twig.

If I am not clear:

today we must control load order for ensuring pre-definition of super classes:

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/app.base.js'
               '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/app.inheritancelevel1.js'
               '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/app.inheritancelevel2.js'
               '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/app.inheritancelevel3.js'
               '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/app.starter.js'
%}...
```

what I want:

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/app.starter.js' %}...

//.../app.starter.js
@import 'app.baseclasses1.js'
@import 'app.baseclasses2.js'
@import 'app.baseclassesN.js'
//.../app.baseclassesX.js
@import 'app.superbaseclassesX.js'
// an so on...
```

The only solution I know is to wrap definitions into functions and make little utility:

```
loadUtil.register('some.package', function(){ 
loadUtil.import('some.base.package');
MyClass=new Class({extends: SuperClassFromSomeBasePackage...});
});
```

Comment: nope , @import is not a javascript keyword. You can look for AMD(requirejs) , or browserify , etc...

Answer (score 1):

I found that RequireJSBundle:

https://github.com/hearsayit/HearsayRequireJSBundle

Answer (score 0):

Write your JavaScript modules in CommonJS format and use [cjsDeliveryBundle](https://github.com/mattcg/cjsDeliveryBundle).

Say your client-side application consists of two modules, pear and pip, where pip requires pear. pip.js would look like this:

```
// pip.js
exports.message = 'I am a pip.';
```

And pear.js would look like this:

```
// pear.js
var pip = require('./pip'); // Assuming pip.js is in the same directory. Note that the .js extension is omitted in CommonJS.

console.log('I am a pear, but also, ' + pip.message);
```

If you point it at pear.js, cjsDelivery will automatically resolve the dependencies and compile the entire modularised application into a single JavaScript file.